# Footer Isn't Width of Parent Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This footer is going to be the death of me.  I've got to be responsive, but now it's not filling the width of my page div.  I've tried auto, 100%, and inherit (it does fill the width, but then the responsiveness is destroyed).

My CSS:

```
.page {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #277FD8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

My HTML:

```
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
              <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfService">Terms Of Service</a>
              <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}AcceptableUsePolicy">Acceptable Use Policy</a>
              <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}WarrentyAndReturnsPolicy">Warranty &amp; Returns Policy</a>
              <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}ThridPartyCopyrightNotices">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
              <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfServicePhone">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
             <br><br><br>
            <p>&copy; 2016 Truespeed Internet Services - All Rights Reserved</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

When I use auto, it falls just short.  When I use 100% it fills the width of the page.

What stupid thing am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added your links into a `.nav-justified` list, which gives you the same behavior but with some more semantic mark up. If you'd like to see a full page view of what I have, go to [This Code Pen](http://codepen.io/jhechtf/full/yJLOVp/), the code I use is below:

```css
.page {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #277FD8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 2px;
}
.footer .container-fluid {
  color: white;
}
.footer .container-fluid a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Terms of Service</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Acceptable use Policy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Warranty &amp; Returns</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Dignissimos.</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>&copy; 2016 Truespeed Internet Services - All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `left: 0;` to the `.footer` class. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byjoynsr/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You're using a UI framework which had lots of margins and padding built in to their components.  There must be margin applied that you don't see.  You could try adding `margin-left:0 !important;` and `margin-right:0 !important;`

One other thing, using absulute or fixed positioning may mess up how your page displays on mobile devices - especially when they go into text entry mode and the keyboard cuts the viewport in half.  Many mobile browsers don't know how to handle absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `left: 0`, `right:0` and `float: left` to the element.